# Is this correct: "a door of opportunity opens up for people"?

Tags: word-choice

So I am debating myself whether the use of  "**of**"  in the sentence:

> a door **of** opportunity opens up for people

is accepted?

And shouldn't "**for**" be more appropriate to use?

Comment: A 'door of opportunity' is a fixed metaphorical expression. See for instance  [assemblenetwork.org](https://www.assemblenetwork.org/doors-of-opportunity#:~:text=Now%20sometimes%20we%20use%20the,do%20something%20new%20or%20different.) 'Window of opportunity' is probably even more common ... and less logical-sounding.

Comment: So who else would it open for? If you said _for dogs_, there would be a reason for the phrase, but _people_ take too much of the blame already.